# Appcelerator - iOS : attributed strings for the TEXT_ALIGNMENT property?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have some labels which are modified with different styles (bold, underline, italic), in addition to the background color.

As explained in the [guide](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Attributed_Strings), i try to use only attributed string for modify the appearance of text.

> If you use the attributedString or the attributedHintText property, do
>   not set any other properties that modify the appearance of text, such
>   as font, color, etc. If you use an attributed string, only use an
>   attributed string. Titanium does not support using attributed strings
>   with other text modifying properties.

Now i need to vertically align the text inside the label. But the option TEXT_ALIGN it doesn't seem to be available as attributed string property.

I need this property

```
Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_TOP
```

[image]

Comment: do `top: 0` and `height: Ti.UI.SIZE` not work out for you?

Comment: Labels have custom width and custom height set

Comment: What about width: 10, height: Ti.UI.SIZE  ?